# GCP Startup Script Execution location

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

By Default GCP VM instances are executing startup script in the /tmp location.

But in my customized ubuntu OS, I have restriction on /tmp location not to execute anything in this location due to security reasons.

Is there anyway to change the default execution path of startup script.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can!

1.You need to go into your VM's  /etc/default/instance_configs.cfg

2.If the file exists, open it and move to [Metadata] section.

3.You may see a “run_dir = ” line which directs the script’s target running folder. You can edit it to set an alternative run directory, for example, /home.

4.Test if the error persists.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if I've understood well; but you can change your startup script directly in the console:

compute engine --> vm instance --> click on your machine in order to see the details --> metadata --> startup script

and then you can change the script there